# Spring MVC Controller NumberFormat Annotation Pattern Issue in BigDecimal

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, numberformatexception

I have a spring controller which is taking multiple `BigDecimal` RequestParams.

My application locale is en_US but just for this controller method I need to bind and convert these `BigDecimal` parameters in de_DE locale (ie. #.###,## > DOT for grouping and COMMA for decimal separator).

These `BigDecimal` values are coming from the UI text boxes and they are already in the `de_DE` format. Here is my controller code which is failing with the following error:

> "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.math.BigDecimal'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException"

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@RequestParam("referenceNumber") String referenceNumber, @RequestParam("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy") Date startDate, @RequestParam("amount1") @NumberFormat(pattern = "#.###,##") BigDecimal amount1, @RequestParam("amount2") @NumberFormat(pattern = "#.###,##") BigDecimal amount2) {

    // Do something and return

}
```

Spring somehow ignores my numberformat pattern. Please note that `DateTimeFormat` annotation works as expected; parsing the startDate parameter in correct form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can debug javascript part of your code. I guess you are sending string value. You can cast it to number in your javascript code

Comment: @user3087839 javascript is irrelevant here; of course i am sending a bunch of strings from view side. Submitting a form is a way of sending string key,value pairs from one side to another. I am asking how to convert these string parameter values in a custom way.

Comment: The annotation works because it gives error like NumberFormatException. It is weird to send string and try to format it later.

Comment: Please give us actual examples of input.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis here is one example: 
referenceNumber:P17-0227
startDate:02-03-2017
amount1:1.000,44
amount2:4.020,31

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [PropertyEditorSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditorSupport.html) to handle the form input as follows:

Create class extending `PropertyEditorSupport` to convert String received from client to [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), for example:

```
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class BigDecimalEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    public void setAsText(String text) {
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
        try {
            Number number = formatter.parse(text);
            BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(number.doubleValue());
            setValue(bigDecimal);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // handle exception here
        }
    }
}
```

And bind it with the controller, as:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new BigDecimalEditor());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(
            @RequestParam("amount") @NumberFormat(pattern = "#.###,##") BigDecimal amount) {
        System.out.println(amount);
        return new ModelAndView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is kind of a workaround though because with customEditors we don't need to use NumberFormat annotation. I really would like to know if it is possible to use NumberFormat annotation with a custom pattern just like the DateTimeFormat pattern.

Comment: +1 This is the best method to me, but you can register a global init binder so you don't have to register one for every controller (http://keenformatics.blogspot.it/2013/08/how-to-create-global-initbinder-in-spring.html). And don't need to use `NumberFormat` annotation in controller parameter, `CustomEditor` will convert the amount also without the annotation.

Comment: As you use spring anyway, you could shorten the content of setAsText by using spring's NumberUtils: `setValue(NumberUtils.parseNumber(text, BigDecimal.class, NumberFormat.getInstance(java.util.Locale.GERMAN)));`

Comment: But take care! The dot is in both variants accepted as a grouping char. So 123.45 would not be an error but 12345.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with:
`@RequestParam(value="amount1", required=false) @NumberFormat(pattern="#0,00") BigDecimal amount1`

Comment: I applied a workaround with PropertyEditorSupport but i will give it a try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: actually what you suggested also works. I gave it a try yesterday and it works nicely.