# There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message available : spring+ thymeleaf

Tags: spring, html, postgresql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i'm creating a formular to add a product_status in PostgreSql  database , but i'm stacked in this erros; i think that i'm not able to send  Bigdecimal value in   because in the class StatusProduits the type of id is Bigdecimal, so i'm not able to add statusProduct in database because the input type dont match with the type of the ID of status_product...

this is the class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.example.demo.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 *
 * @author G557437
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATUT_PRODUITS", catalog = "", schema = "PACKOUT")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "StatutProduits.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM StatutProduits s")})
public class StatutProduits implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_STATUT_PRODUIT")
    private BigDecimal idStatutProduit;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "LIBELLE")
    private String libelle;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "CREE_PAR")
    private String creePar;
    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCreation;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "MAJ_PAR")
    private String majPar;
    @Column(name = "DATE_MAJ")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateMaj;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idStatutProduit")
    private List<Produits> produitsList;

    public StatutProduits() {
    }

    public StatutProduits(BigDecimal idStatutProduit) {
        this.idStatutProduit = idStatutProduit;
    }

    public StatutProduits(BigDecimal idStatutProduit, String code, String libelle, String creePar) {
        this.idStatutProduit = idStatutProduit;
        this.code = code;
        this.libelle = libelle;
        this.creePar = creePar;
    }

    public BigDecimal getIdStatutProduit() {
        return idStatutProduit;
    }

    public void setIdStatutProduit(BigDecimal idStatutProduit) {
        this.idStatutProduit = idStatutProduit;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getLibelle() {
        return libelle;
    }

    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }

    public String getCreePar() {
        return creePar;
    }

    public void setCreePar(String creePar) {
        this.creePar = creePar;
    }

    public Date getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }

    public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }

    public String getMajPar() {
        return majPar;
    }

    public void setMajPar(String majPar) {
        this.majPar = majPar;
    }

    public Date getDateMaj() {
        return dateMaj;
    }

    public void setDateMaj(Date dateMaj) {
        this.dateMaj = dateMaj;
    }

    public List<Produits> getProduitsList() {
        return produitsList;
    }

    public void setProduitsList(List<Produits> produitsList) {
        this.produitsList = produitsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idStatutProduit != null ? idStatutProduit.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof StatutProduits)) {
            return false;
        }
        StatutProduits other = (StatutProduits) object;
        if ((this.idStatutProduit == null && other.idStatutProduit != null) || (this.idStatutProduit != null && !this.idStatutProduit.equals(other.idStatutProduit))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.sagemcom.tn.entities.StatutProduits[ idStatutProduit=" + idStatutProduit + " ]";
    }

}
```

the controller :

```
package com.example.demo.web;

import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.example.demo.dao.StatutProduitsRepository;
import com.example.demo.entities.StatutProduits;


@Controller
public class StatutProduitsController {

    @Autowired
    StatutProduitsRepository statutproduitsrepository ;
    @RequestMapping(value="/index")
    public String index( Model model,
        @RequestParam(name="page", defaultValue="0")int p,
        @RequestParam(name="size", defaultValue="3")int s) 
    {
        Page<StatutProduits> pagestatutsproduits = statutproduitsrepository.findAll(new PageRequest(p,s));
        model.addAttribute("listStatutProduits",pagestatutsproduits.getContent());
        int [] pages = new int [pagestatutsproduits.getTotalPages()];
        model.addAttribute("pages",pages);
        model.addAttribute("size",s);
        model.addAttribute("pageCourante",p);
        return "statutproduits" ;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/form", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String save( Model model,StatutProduits statproduit) {
        statutproduitsrepository.save(statproduit);
        return "Confirmation";
    }
}
```

the HTML page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}"
    />

<title>Statut du produit</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Statut d'un produit</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <form th:action="@{save}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">ID</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="id"
                            th:value="${statproduit.idStatutProduit}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">Code</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code"
                    th:value="${statproduit.code}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">Cree par</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="creePar"
                          th:value="${statproduit.creePar}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">Date creation</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date"  name="dateCreation"
                    th:value="${statproduit.dateCreation}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">Date maj</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="DateMaj"
                    th:value="${statproduit.dateMaj}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">Libelle</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="libelle"
                    th:value="${statproduit.libelle}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">Maj par</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="majPar"
                     th:value="${statproduit.majPar}"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

                </div>
             </form>    
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your `<form th:action="@{save}" method="post">` says that you go to endpoint `/save` with a post request. You dont have any request mapping for that!

Comment: '@{save}' call the methode 'save ´ at the controller @patrick

Comment: that would be new for me. I would suggest to change your Requestmapping like that: @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: @Patrick: the problem is  here :

`<div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label">ID</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="id"
                            th:value="${statproduit.idStatutProduit}"/>
</div>`

how to change the type  into the input to Bigdecimal not number ?

Comment: Quite a few issues with this code and so I would suggest looking through the Thymeleaf and Spring documentation.  You should have `th:object` on your form and have the `th:action` formatted correctly with a slash.  This can help you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056112/spring-mvc-controller-numberformat-annotation-pattern-issue-in-bigdecimal.  Also have a look at Project Lombok to make your beans easier to manage.